# Align two subtables in a centered way and place them closer to the main text

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I'm new to LaTeX and currently writing my master's thesis.
I am trying to create two subtables stacked on top of each other, using the `subcaption` package.

Here is the code:

```
The file was read into a dataframe and pivoted longer, using month, day and hour as indices, the grid points as `column` and the values as the `values` column. This turned a 8760 x 185 dataframe into a 1594320 x 5 dataframe, as shown in Table \ref{tab:ill_preproc}. 

\begin{table}[h!]
    \caption{Global caption}
    \centering
    \begin{subtable}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            Month & Day & Hour & Point 0 & Point 1 & Point ... & Point 182 \\ [0.5ex]
            \hline
            01 & 01 & 0.5 & ... & ... & ... & ... \\
            01 & 01 & 1.5 & ... & ... & ... & ... \\
            01 & 01 & 2.5 & ... & ... & ... & ... \\
            01 & 01 & 3.5 & ... & ... & ... & ... \\
            ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... \\
            12 & 31 & 23.5 & ... & ... & ... & ... \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Before pre-processing}
        \label{tab:before_preproc}
    \end{subtable}
    \begin{subtable}[t]{0.5\linewidth} \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            Month & Day & Hour & Point & Values\\ [0.5ex]
            \hline
            01 & 01 & 0.5 & 0 & ...  \\
            01 & 01 & 1.5 & 1 & ...  \\
            01 & 01 & 2.5 & 2 & ... \\
            01 & 01 & 3.5 & 3 & ... \\
            ... & ... & ... & ... & ... \\
            12 & 31 & 23.5 & 182 & ... \\
            \hline
            \end{tabular}
        \caption{After pre-processing}
        \label{tab:after_preproc}
    \end{subtable}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}
```

And here is what I get:

[image: Result of stacked tables, aligned by first columns]

Now, there are two things I don't like about this result and I would like to change, and one that would be a "nice-to-know":

1. How do I align the subtables so that it's not the first columns of each that align vertically, but the subtables are symmetrical wrt the vertical center of the page? To be more clear, I'd like the "Hour" column of the first subtable to be roughly vertically aligned to the "Month" column of the second.
2. How do I decrease the distance from the table to the text above?

And the nice-to-know: is there a way to specify the vertical distance between the subtable and the subcaption, and between subtables?

Comment: If you want both table stacked on top of each other, why do you limit both subtable environments to 0.5\textwidth, each? Using `\begin{subtable}{\textwidth}` for both environments should result in horizontally centered tables. (You might also want to add `\centering` to the first `subtable`.

Comment: Concerning the "vertical distance between subtable and subcaption": you can adapt `\abovecaptionskip` and `\belowcaptionskip` locally by writing `\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{6pt}` inside the `subtable`-environment.

Comment: Are the entries in the columns "Day", "Month" and "Hour" identical in both tables? If you, you could probably also combine them into one table.

Comment: Thank you very much! For leandriis: I don't want to combine them into a single table, because the first is a table before pivoting longer and the second is the result.

Comment: Still, the table appears very far from the text above; how do I solve that?

Comment: your above code does not include any text above the table -- would you like to show what part of the code created the problem above the table

Comment: Hi, I have included the paragraph above (not all text is reported in the figure).

Comment: @SteP have alook at the edit to the answer -- is the inconsistency still there?

Comment: Hi, it's working fine now, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the vertical alignment  see the answer below -- for the caption see the comments above

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\hrule % just to illustrate width of textblock
\begin{table}[H]
\begin{subtable}{1\linewidth}
\centering
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            Month & Day & Hour & Point 0 & Point 1 & Point ... & Point 182 \\ [0.5ex]
            \hline
            01 & 01 & 0.5 & ... & ... & ... & ... \\
            01 & 01 & 1.5 & ... & ... & ... & ... \\
            01 & 01 & 2.5 & ... & ... & ... & ... \\
            01 & 01 & 3.5 & ... & ... & ... & ... \\
            ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... \\
            12 & 31 & 23.5 & ... & ... & ... & ... \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
\caption{SUBTBL1}

\vspace{0.5cm}

        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            Month & Day & Hour & Point & Values\\ [0.5ex]
            \hline
            01 & 01 & 0.5 & 0 & ...  \\
            01 & 01 & 1.5 & 1 & ...  \\
            01 & 01 & 2.5 & 2 & ... \\
            01 & 01 & 3.5 & 3 & ... \\
            ... & ... & ... & ... & ... \\
            12 & 31 & 23.5 & 182 & ... \\
            \hline
            \end{tabular}
\caption{SUBTBL2}
\end{subtable}%

\caption{Overall table caption}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT -- with text above the table**

[image]

MWE

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\hrule % just to illustrate width of textblock
The file was read into a dataframe and pivoted longer, using month, day and hour as indices, the grid points as `column` and the values as the `values` column. This turned a 8760 x 185 dataframe into a 1594320 x 5 dataframe, as shown in Table . 
\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{subtable}{1\linewidth}
\centering
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            Month & Day & Hour & Point 0 & Point 1 & Point ... & Point 182 \\ [0.5ex]
            \hline
            01 & 01 & 0.5 & ... & ... & ... & ... \\
            01 & 01 & 1.5 & ... & ... & ... & ... \\
            01 & 01 & 2.5 & ... & ... & ... & ... \\
            01 & 01 & 3.5 & ... & ... & ... & ... \\
            ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... \\
            12 & 31 & 23.5 & ... & ... & ... & ... \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
\caption{SUBTBL1}

\vspace{0.5cm}

        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            Month & Day & Hour & Point & Values\\ [0.5ex]
            \hline
            01 & 01 & 0.5 & 0 & ...  \\
            01 & 01 & 1.5 & 1 & ...  \\
            01 & 01 & 2.5 & 2 & ... \\
            01 & 01 & 3.5 & 3 & ... \\
            ... & ... & ... & ... & ... \\
            12 & 31 & 23.5 & 182 & ... \\
            \hline
            \end{tabular}
\caption{SUBTBL2}
\end{subtable}%

\caption{Overall table caption}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```